# Rotate Item Using Mouse Using Player Objects Space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The title is hopefully not too bad, however the issue I'm facing seems to be related to the "space" being used and thus seems important.
So in short, I'm working on a game in which the user can rotate an object using the mouse. It works to a degree only, this is the current code (currently being called upon the update function):

```
    float mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    var delta = Mouse.current.delta.ReadValue();
    mouseX += delta.x;
    mouseY += delta.y;

    mouseX *= mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    mouseY *= mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    float XaxisRotation = (mouseX * rotationSpeedMultiplier) / grabbedObjectMass; 
    float YaxisRotation = ((mouseY*-1) * rotationSpeedMultiplier) / grabbedObjectMass; 
    grabbedObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * XaxisRotation, Space.Self);                        
    grabbedObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * YaxisRotation, Space.Self);
```

It works in the sense that I can rotate the object. However it immediately feels bad once you turn it too much and thus it no longer behaves in a relatable way. I'm using Space.Self and that means that rotation uses the objects own X,Y,Z coordinates, Space.World would use the scenes X,Y,Z as far as I understand it. This is with Space.Self using my Photoshop skills just to illustrate the problem:
[object specific rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stW59.jpg)

Now what I want instead is that it will always rotate "properly" according to the players perspective or the players X/Y/Z. So no matter what side I look on, it should just rotate the same as it uses the player as space - if that makes any sense. However, the only options seem to be Space.Self and Space.World.

I've seen games do it so it's definitely possible and probably not super complicated, but I just don't know how yet. I've tried this alternative code (copied and adapted) from the Unity Docs, however it behaves exactly the same as the code above using Space.Self:

```
    float mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    var delta = Mouse.current.delta.ReadValue();
    mouseX += delta.x;
    mouseY += delta.y;
    mouseX *= mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    mouseY *= mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float XaxisRotation = (mouseX * rotationSpeedMultiplier) / grabbedObjectMass; 
    float YaxisRotation = (mouseY * rotationSpeedMultiplier) / grabbedObjectMass;
    Vector3 EulerAngleVelocity = new Vector3(YaxisRotation, XaxisRotation, 0f);
    Rigidbody rb = grabbedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(EulerAngleVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotation);
```

I honestly don't fully understand rotation, Quaternions etc. just yet. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: The rotation vectors you're looking for are (based on the fact you used right and down) probably transform.right and transform.up from the camera. If you orient the axis of rotation according to the camera and rotate in world space, that's probably what you think of as "properly".

Comment: I was clearly not as clear as I hoped I would be! :D
So here's a gif from within the current project: https://imgur.com/a/IXMNU1A
& a gif from Ghost Hunters Corp doing the same: https://imgur.com/a/JcEunG3

In both I tilt the item held towards and away from the camera and then turn it slightly to the right, then towards / away from cam and so on.

For GHC the movements are finnicky and mouse speed too high, to explain the jerky movements.

As you can see in the gifs, in GHC it always tilts towards the players cam no matter how far I turn it to the right, whereas in my project it doesnt

Comment: The changes you suggested simply swap things around, instead of moving my mouse down and the item rotating up, it'll then rotate down, same for left / right. The issue with the axis remains that I can't figure out but I hope those gifs show exactly what I mean.

Comment: If up is down, multiply by a negative. First gif looks like camera(world?) up and object local right. Second looks like camera up and camera right.

Comment: Tilting "towards" the player camera is "rotating clockwise around the camera.right axis".

Comment: In my specific case I have a player object6, part of the player object is the players camera. The object being held is positioned in front of the camera using another object that is, sort of, always around 1-2m in front of the players direct view, sort of simulating an arms length. The rotation of the item doesn't revolve around the camera at all. In my understanding, if I were to rotate the item around the camera it would literally go around the players perspective and out of view, no? Since it's first person perspective and all that.

Comment: Don't rotate around the camera. Take the axis of the camera, and in world space, rotate your object around those axis transposed to be centred over your object.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to rotate in world space to limit the number of space conversions needed. The rotations you're looking for are always "from the players perspective" which loosely translates to mean "the axis of rotation are determined by the camera".

Here are two ways to think about (and code) these rotations:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera camera;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform targetTransform;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 rotationSpeed;

    private Vector3 previousMousePosition;

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mouseMovement = Input.mousePosition - previousMousePosition;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            //RotateObjectUsingAxis(mouseMovement);
            RotateObjectUsingOrientedEulers(mouseMovement);
        }

        previousMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        DrawDebugs();
    }

    private void RotateObjectUsingOrientedEulers(Vector3 mouseMovement)
    {
        // Apply mouse input as euler rotations
        // Mouse Y rotates around the X axis, Mouse X rotates around Y axis
        Vector3 scaledInput = new Vector3(mouseMovement.y, mouseMovement.x, 0);
        // Scale input by time to smooth a little
        scaledInput *= Time.deltaTime;
        // Scale input by desired rotation speeds
        scaledInput.Scale(rotationSpeed);
        // Orient the rotation amounts we've made with the camera's rotation
        Vector3 orientedRotations = camera.transform.rotation * scaledInput;
        // Apply rotation in world space
        targetTransform.Rotate(orientedRotations, Space.World);
    }

    private void RotateObjectUsingAxis(Vector3 mouseMovement)
    {
        // Mouse X rotates around axis created by camera.up
        targetTransform.Rotate(camera.transform.up * mouseMovement.x * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed.x, Space.World);
        // Mouse Y rotates around axis created by camera.right
        targetTransform.Rotate(camera.transform.right * mouseMovement.y * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed.y, Space.World);
    }

    private void DrawDebugs()
    {
        float length = 2;

        // camera axis positioned over target in world
        Debug.DrawLine(targetTransform.position, targetTransform.position + camera.transform.up * length, Color.green, Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.DrawLine(targetTransform.position, targetTransform.position + camera.transform.right * length, Color.green, Time.deltaTime);
        // this one isn't used.
        Debug.DrawLine(targetTransform.position, targetTransform.position + camera.transform.forward * length, Color.blue, Time.deltaTime);

        // if you need help visualizing the "local" axis of the target object
        //Debug.DrawLine(targetTransform.position, targetTransform.position + targetTransform.transform.up * length, Color.yellow, Time.deltaTime);
        //Debug.DrawLine(targetTransform.position, targetTransform.position + targetTransform.transform.right * length, Color.yellow, Time.deltaTime);
        //Debug.DrawLine(targetTransform.position, targetTransform.position + targetTransform.transform.forward * length, Color.red, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

The `transform.Rotate` method will always rotate "in place". It doesn't change the position of the transform. A transform's orientation vectors are normalized, so they don't care about position either. That's why we don't need to worry about applying the camera's axis to the target's rotation, the target won't rotate around the camera. It rotates around the axis created by the camera.